# Regex for all alphabets

Tags: javascript, regex

i need a regex for all alphabets. I have an input and target text. Both of them can be belong different alphabets. I mean they can be belong chinese, latin, cyrillic and any others alphabet.

I need a regex for multi language input and multi language target text.

Is there anybody has any idea about this? How can i write this regex ?

I will use this with javascript. But i think there should be common regex for java and javascript also for this problem.

Comment: really! i know they are not same. regex is common so i can use same regex for JAVA, JAVASCRIPT OR GROOVY !

Comment: @erimerturk No you can't. See her the flavour comparisson on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html). javascript is the "ECMA" column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use "|" this character as a separator, so it is speacial for me. Key can be any character except of "|". it solve my problems thanks for answers. And it can be used with javascript, java and groovy. I tested it, worked.

```
var keyPrefix ="\\|[\u0000-\u007B\u007D-\uFFEF]*";
var keySuffix = "[\u0000-\u007B\u007D-\uFFEF]*\\|";
var searchkey = keyPrefix + key.toLowerCase() + keySuffix;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are in Java (not in javascript!) you can use unicode properties, e.g.

`\P{L}` any kind of letter from any language.

See [regular-expressions.info/unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) for more informations.

**For Javascript:**

There is a lib from [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) and some plugins [XRegExp Unicode plugins](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) that extends the javasript regex features. That adds support for Unicode categories, scripts, and blocks.

With those libs you would be able to use `\p{L}` with javascript.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576945/javascript-regular-expression-for-punctuation-international/7578937#7578937) for a small example

Comment: i couldnt use this for javascript. I need for javascript. So this not solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

Some regex engines support special character for all Unicode letters:

```
\p{L}
```

Or you can use `\w` - letter, digit, underscore

Comment: i couldnt use " \p{L}" for javascript. And "\w" is not enough for example, input is "ığç" and target text is "ığçss". So this not solution for me.