# Regex for alphanumerical characters but also other alphabets such as Chinese, Japanese, Cyrillic

Tags: javascript, regex, expression, alphabet

my knowledge with Regex is limited and I'm trying to keep the text of the following sentence but remove the special characters such as dashes:

```
Λένα & Πλάτωνος - Red Axes Remixes
Sugai Ken 鯰上 - On The Quakefish
```

Anyone knows how to deal with different alphabets?
I tried `([^\w'])+` but it removes the essential characters...

Thanks!

Comment: Which PL do you use? This topic maybe help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Depends on the regex flavor/programming language/tool. Try `[^\p{L}\p{M}']+`

Comment: I'm using Nodejs in a Jade template

Comment: Ok, JS. Use XRegExp. Or see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34854255/3832970).

Comment: I don't mean only Cyrillic alphabet but also Japanese, Chinese and so on...

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to turn this around and specifically *remove* specific characters and leave everything else alone?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

`[^\x00-\x1F\x21-\x7F]*

This should match anything not in the regular ascii set and space. You can update that to include whatever other regualar ascii characters you would like to include. As you can see, I have 1 ranges, so that it includes the 'space' character.

Obviously, you could go the other way around and do an inclusive match, making it easier to include the exact characters to match:

`[\x80-\x{FFFF} &]*