# Regex name validation (complex logic)

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I am trying to validate a name, with the following rules:

1. Case insensitive
2. Only letters, blank space, accented characters.
3. At least one blank space followed with some letter or letters `John D` or `john Doe` or `John X Doe`
4. Cannot have multiple spaces at once `John     X     Doe`
5. Length must be at least 5 (with space) and at maximum 80

I came up with `(?i)^[a-z]+(?:[\ ]?[a-z]+)*$`

https://regex101.com/r/bQ5oO9/1

Some problems:

1. Is validating only 'Name'
2. Is not validating the length
3. Is not accepting accented characters

Comment: about the accents, check out [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics)  `[A-zÀ-ÿ]` apparently matches all letters and letters with accents.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `Is validating only 'Name'`  in my testing, it's matching the last name too.

Comment: To validate the length, you can check the length of your match.  If you're using attribute validation, you can add a `[MinLength]` attribute and a `[MaxLength]` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{5,80}$)\p{L}*(?: \p{L}+)+$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZ1gJ3/1) (I recommend `\z` rather than `$` since `\z` matches *the vary* end of the string, however, if you use a plain space in the pattern,  that is irrelevant).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{5,80}$)` - the length must be at least 5 and at most 80 chars all in all
- `\p{L}*` - zero or more letters (*use `+` instead of `*` if the string cannot start with a space*)
- `(?: \p{L}+)+` - 1 or more sequences of one space and one or more letters (this meets your *Cannot have multiple spaces at once* and *At least one blank space followed with some letter or letters* requirements)
- `$` - end of string.

Note that `\p{L}` matches any Unicode base letters, thus meeting your *Only letters, blank space, accented characters* and *case insensitive* requirements.

If you need to also support diacritic symbols, replace  `\p{L}` with `[\p{L}\p{M}]`.