# JavaScript Regex to match 2 words and an whitespace character with length limitations

Tags: javascript, regex

I actually got this regex `^[A-zÀ-ÿ ]{3,50}$` or `^[A-zÀ-ÿ\s]{3,50}$` that finds 3 to 50 characters of this specific alphabets.
I need a new regex to accept only 1 whitespace character `\s` maintaining the {3,50} limitation.

I tried `^[A-zÀ-ÿ]+\s[A-zÀ-ÿ]{3,50}$` but it is limiting the last *tuple* to 3-50 and not the whole thing.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, to match ASCII letters, you need to use `[A-Za-z]`, not `[A-z]` (see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926)).

As for the single obligatory whitespace, it can be added as in your attempt, and the length limitation can be added in the form of a lookahead:

```
/^(?=.{3,50}$)[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]+\s[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]+$/
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ioFXrA/1).

Comment: I found that accent expression here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics/26900132#26900132 Anyways thanks, your expression is doing what I want.