# Regex pattern in HTML form name validation

Tags: html, regex

I'm making a form in HTML that has a name field that I'd like to validate with the HTML `pattern` attribute.

I would like to allow any letters (including with accents) as well as - . , ' and space. (added in edit to clarify)

Here was my attempt:

`Nome e Cognome: <input type="text" name="nome" required pattern="^[\p{L}\p{M} \-\.',]*$" placeholder="Mario Rossi">`

However, when I input invalid data like `John" Doe?` the form doesn't throw an error. Why?

Comment: What are the unwanted characters ?

Comment: I would like to allow any letters (including with accents) as well as - . , ' and space.

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex doesn't look quite right, but without knowing your exact requirements it's hard to write the one you want!

Try this: `/^[a-zÀ-ÿ ,.'-]+$/i` It will match first and last names, and allow for only the symbols commonly found in names.

For this to work, you also need to put it in a `<form>` (of bind it to a button). For example:

```html
<form action="/submit-name/">
    Nome e Cognome: <input type="text" name="nome" required pattern="^[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ ,.'-]+$"   placeholder="Mario Rossi">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: he wants to include accents

Comment: Okay, thanks! Could someone explain why the Unicode tags I used don't work/aren't the best way to do this? One [thing I read](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) said that accented characters can be coded as two separate code points so I was trying to cover all my bases. Also, why the `+` in place of the `*`?

Comment: Your right, and allowing for accents sometimes gets tricky. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics. You could also do something like this: `/^[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+$/i`