# Angular 4 : How to define custom validator for input which wont allow numbers?

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to create a custom validator in angular 4 project which will only allow characters other than numbers to be typed.

So Far I have tried multiple options but none seem to work.

I am doing something like this:

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    ...
    city: new FormControl('', validateCity)
  });
}
```

**Validator**

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

function validateCity(c: FormControl) {
  let CITY_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]/i;

  return CITY_REGEXP.test(c.value) ? null : {
    validateCity: {
      valid: false
    }
  };
}
```

am I doing something wrong?
thanks

Comment: Can you please plunker/fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you just have a `regex` you could just use the `pattern` validator

```
city: new FormControl('',  Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z]'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is not correct:

```js
let CITY = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]/i;
console.log(CITY.test('Hello9'))
```

You need a regex that matches only characters and spaces:

```js
let re=/^[A-Za-z ]+$/

console.log (re.test('Barcelona')) //true
console.log(re.test('Los Angeles')) //true
console.log(re.test('Paris 9')) //false
```

But maybe you need to allow accents, umlauts ... so you can check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics)