# Find all accented words (diacriticals) using grep?

Tags: grep

I have a large list of words in a text file (one word per line)  Some words have accented characters (diacriticals).  How can I use grep to display only the lines that contain accented characters?

Comment: That returns this error: usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics) answer, you might just match a range of unicode characters `[\u00C0-\u017F]`

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I have found, for a larger class of characters ("What words are not pure ASCII?") is using PCRE with `-P` option:

```
grep -P "[\x7f-\xff]" filename
```

This will find UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1(5) (Latin1, win1252, cp850) accented characters alike.

Comment: A side note. See the ASCII table. A-Z and a-z are represented by \x41-\x5a and \x61-\x7a respectively. Thus `grep -Po "[^\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a]"`  which greps for all characters except A-Za-z works.

Comment: Beware that this sometimes doesn't work with file arguments (even though it does when grep is reading from stdin !?). You may need to add `LC_ALL=C ` in front to make it work : `LC_ALL=C grep -P "[\x7f-\xff]" filename`

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution.  First strip the accents using "iconv" then do a "diff" for lines in the original file:

```
cat text-file | iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT > noaccents-file
diff text-file noaccents-file | grep '<'
```