# JavaScript match accents on array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to do a function which returns all matches in a given array of strings from an input using RegEx. The code is the following:

```
function checkWord(input, myArray) {
    let reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*\\s*\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');

    return myArray.filter(function (f) {
        if (f.match(reg)) {
            return f;
        } 
   }); 
}


$input.on("keyup", function () {
    let result = checkWord($input.val(), arr);
    $divResult.html(result); 
});
```

I have this implemented on the "keyup" event from an input, it returns all matches but doesn't work with accented words, how can I check and match accented words inside the array of strings?
I mean, if the array contains accented words, it won't match non-accented words from the input.

I'm testing it with this array:

```
let arr = [ "Álvaro", "Lucía", "Ramón", "á", "é", "í", "ó", "ú", "Alvaro", "Lucia", "David", "Joaquín", "Pepe", "Paco", "Barça", "äe", "ë", "ï", "ö", "ü", "à", "è", "ì", "ò", "ù" ];
```

I've tried all RegEx suggested on comments but I can't get this to work :(

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like `checkWord` request 2 parameters, but you only send one `checkWord($input.val())`

Comment: Are you sure this code works? Your `checkWord` function requires 2 arguments and it does not check for missing 2nd argument, but you call it with a single argument. Re matching accents, `\w` does not seem to include these, try `[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]` instead (or even better, read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics).

Comment: Ye sorry forgot to add it here to simplify the code, In my code the array is global, the code works, sorry about that, I just edited the post.

Comment: In Chrome and ECMAScript 2018 compatible JS engines, you may use `new RegExp(input.split('').join('[\\p{L}\\p{N}_]*\\s*[\\p{L}\\p{N}_]*').replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}_]+/gu, ""), 'iu')`. Else, you need to use `XRegExp` and use `[\\pL\\pN_]` like patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the RegExp by:

```
let reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]*\\s*[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]*').replace(/[^A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]/, ""), 'i');
```

While `\w` allowes all alphabetic characters(meaning `[a-zA-Z]`), `[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]` also allowes accented characters. And `\W` means all BUT alphabetic characters(`[^a-zA-Z]`) and `[^A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]` also doesn't allow accented characters.

Comment: Please explain why to use this regular expression and how it works.