# Remove non alphanumeric chars from string preserving accentuated chars

Tags: ruby

I need to remove the chars such as "+", "/", "_" and similar from strings in order to perform a search method.

According to other question here, I had this using the gsub method, the problem is that it also substitutes the accentuated letters, which I don't want to:

`string.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')`

EDIT: The languagues I need to support are spanish and catalonian.

Is there any way to adapt the expresion to preserve the letters with accents?

Comment: Which accents in particular do you wish to preserve? What languages are you dealing with?

Comment: Spanish and Catalonian, so I need to support both acute and grave accents

Comment: `string.gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, '')` removes punctuation characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both answers given here so far are plain wrong.

There are two types of accents in the modern unicode: composed and combined diacritics (decomposed.) With Ruby 2.3+ everything is easy:

```
"Barça".unicode_normalize(:nfc).scan(/\p{L}/)
#⇒ ["B", "a", "r", "ç", "a"]
```

The above will work no matter how “ç” was constructed, as a Latin1 composed character, or as a combined diacritics.

That said, to remove all *non* letters, one would do:

```
"Barça".unicode_normalize(:nfc).gsub(/[^\p{L}]/, '')
```

Before Ruby 2.3 there was no standard way to normalize a string to composed form, and while for “mañana” the simple range `À..ÿ` would work (composed form,) for “mañana” it won’t (combined diacritics.) You might ensure there is a difference yourself by copy-pasting both into your `irb` shell.

Comment: This answer seems much more sensible and comprehensive than mine. I'll have to remember this in future; thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I have to use `"Barça".unicode_normalize(:nfc).gsub(/[^\p{L}]/, '')` since I'm in Ruby 2.3.1, but it works.

Comment: Oh, indeed, I mistakenly thought `unicode_normalize` was introduced in `2.5` only. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `POSIX bracket expression`. You will find all needed [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) in the ruby-docs.

In your case you can use either:

```
string.gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/, '')
```

or:

```
string.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, '')
```

From the documentation:

> /[[:alnum:]]/ - Alphabetic and numeric character
>
> /[[:alpha:]]/ - Alphabetic character

Comment: Looks promising but it doesn't work, `"tórica".gsub(/[^[:alnum]]/, '')` returns `"a"`

Comment: Sorry I am missing one semicolon `:` in the example. It is edited now.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I will accept mudasobwa though since he answered before, still appreciated for your answer.

Comment: @ErnestoG no, this does not work. Try `"mañana".gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/, '')`.

Comment: You are right sorry. It is weird though, if I type "mañana" myself it works, if I copy your "mañana" it doesn't (it outputs "manana")

Comment: @ErnestoG it’s not weird and I explained this behavior in my answer. When you type it using your keyboard, it spits out the _already combined_ value. Even the length of these strings differs: `%w|mañana mañana|.map(&:length) #⇒ [7, 6]`. That’s the reason of using `unicode_normalize(:nfc)` and that’s why I wrote other answers here are _wrong_.

Comment: Perfectly clear now, thank you for such an accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics), the regex character range for many, but not all, accented characters is `À-ÿ`. Therefore, to match these too, you can simply add this to your existing ranges:

```
string.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]/, '')
```

It largely depends on the accents you're looking for, since there are too many accents to easily match *all* of them. This example regex will preserve for instance acute/grave accents, but misses crescents:

```
puts "I went to a café.".gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]/, '') # Iwenttoacafé
puts "Ahoj, světe!".gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]/, '')      # Ahojsvte
```

This might be fine for your use case, but if you're dealing with, say, Czech text, you might need additional character ranges to match crescents.

Comment: Try `"mañana"`.