# Validation input field Fullname(Firstname,Lastname) - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, input

Need validation for full name(first name/last name - 1 input field). I'm new in this sphere and can't formulate the right syntax maybe will work with a regular expression too

```
<form name="myForm" action="#" id="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
            <div class="field"><span class="input"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="Fullname" placeholder="Full Name" >
                </span>


function validateForm() {
var name= document.getElementById('name').value;
var x = name.indexOf(" ");
var fname = name.substring(0, x);
var lname = name.substring(x).trim();
if ( 17 < fname.value.length < 5 || 4 > lname.value.length > 17 || x.value.length != 1) {
    alert("try again")
    return false;
 }
 alert("OK")
return true;
}
```

The field (1 field) should contain 2 words which should be from 3 to 20 symbols.

EDIT:It seems work..finally!

```js
function input (name) {
  let fullNameArr = name.split('')
  const space = ' '
  let firstName = ''
  if (fullNameArr.includes(space)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fullNameArr.length; i++) {
      if (!firstName.includes(space)) {
        firstName += fullNameArr[i]
      }
    }
  }
  firstName = fullNameArr.splice(0, firstName.length)
  const lastName = fullNameArr
  if (firstName.length > 3 && firstName.length <= 21 && lastName.length >= 3 && lastName.length <= 20 && lastName.includes(space) === false) {
    console.log(firstName)
    console.log(lastName)
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid Name')
    return false
  }
}
input('Todor Markov')
```

Comment: What if my name is "Johnny Van Patton Jr." re: 2 words

Comment: these are 4 words..The requiments are for 2 words..

Comment: Typically I see this`17 < fname.value.length < 5 ` as `fname.value.length < 21 &&  fname.value.length > 2` for your 3 to 20

Comment: `17 < fname.value.length < 5` with "foobar" as `fname.value`, this will be executed like this : `17 < "foobar".length < 5` => `17 < true` => `false`. So `17 < fname.value.length < 5` will always be evaluated to `false`

Comment: This is not the world's best regex to solve it but try this regex ```^\w{3,20} \w{3,20}$``` ```/^\w{3,20} \w{3,20}$/.test("hello world")```

Comment: but make sure you trim the name before applying the regex

Comment: @greedchikara Be careful with `\w`, since it does not match accentuated letters. For example `/^\w{3,20} \w{3,20}$/.test("Sébastien Lor")` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: what about space with regExp..

Comment: @Seblor totally agree with you on that, this is the simplest regex from top of my mind

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics for anyone who is curious about the accentuated letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model makes several assumptions about names. Having first name and last name as separate input boxes is typically done to remove this barrier.

From a UX standpoint, if you were not going to have separate fields, you'd need some validation with a tooltip that checked if the user has more than one space that alerts them they must type `FirstName LastName`.

From a regex validation view, here's a catch all to ensure it's valid.
`/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i.test("Johnny 'Van' Pat-ton Jr.")`
No numbers, but allow letters and the special characters `,.'-`.

Comment: Your regex won't match accentuated letters, which are very common in many non-english names.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function input (name) {
  let fullNameArr = name.split('')
  const space = ' '
  let firstName = ''
  if (fullNameArr.includes(space)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fullNameArr.length; i++) {
      if (!firstName.includes(space)) {
        firstName += fullNameArr[i]
      }
    }
  }
  firstName = fullNameArr.splice(0, firstName.length)
  const lastName = fullNameArr
  if (firstName.length > 3 && firstName.length <= 21 && lastName.length >= 3 && lastName.length <= 20 && lastName.includes(space) === false) {
    console.log(firstName)
    console.log(lastName)
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid Name')
    return false
  }
}
input('Todor Markov')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).