# multilingual letters for name checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to use regex to check multilingual names.

Letters like: üöäõ

My code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("lettersonly_firstName",function function_name(value,element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/g.test(value);
}, "Plese enter a valid first Name.");
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics. 
Not only does it answer your question, it also is a great example of how to ask a question!!

Comment: Why use a regex at all for a first name? What are multilingual names? Chinese characters? [It's fairly easy to be too restrictive](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Just simply accept what the user enters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concrete Javascript Regex for Accented Characters (Diacritics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose particular Unicode blocks explicitly by providing a range of characters:

> [-a-zA-ZÀ-ÿĀ-ſƀ-ɏ ']+

It covers characters , `-`, `'`. Which could be a part of the name in different cultures.

Plus these Unicode blocks:

- `a-zA-Z`, [Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block))
- `À-ÿ`, [Latin-1 Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)) with `×` and `÷` included in the middle
- `Ā-ſ`, [Latin Extended-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-A)
- `ƀ-ɏ`, [Latin Extended-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-B)

If it's not required, you can remove the last one. Or you can also add `Latin Extended-C`, `Latin Extended-D`, and `Latin Extended-E`.

[Latin script in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode)

If you need, you can add Cyrillic also:

- `Ѐ-ӿ`, [Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_(Unicode_block))

---

Don't forget to test your Regex. Even better is to write automated tests against some name list.

You can check out the regex and play with it there: https://regex101.com/r/ZfEE98/2