# Allowing for spaces in this regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following: `this.state.message.match(/^\/m\s+(\w+):\s*(.*)/)`

This looks for a message that contains: `/m name: message` where its failing if your name has a space in it: `/m name something: message`. What would be the proper way to update this such that the name can have spaces or other characters other then just `name`

for example: `\m Character name: message` fails, but `\m Sample: message` does not.

thoughts?

Comment: Should the line start with a forward slash or a backslash? One of your examples uses `/`, the other uses ``\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add space to the character list, no?

```
/^\/m\s+(\w+[\w| ]*):\s*(.*)/
```

Change `\w` to `[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]` to accept also accents and diacritics [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics)

Comment: How about this.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat `\w+\s+`(word characters, followed by spaces) zero or more times:

```
^\\m\s+((?:\w+\s+)*\w+):\s*(.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/RDl628/1

Comment: Would break if character name ends with space

Comment: True, but that sounds quite unlikely, I've never seen any login system permitting trailing (or leading) spaces in a username or display name

Comment: True, but if basing on that assumption, there will be no system allowing empty login either ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^\/m\s+(\w+\s+)*?(\w+):\s*(.*)/
```

Comment: This adds an additional capturing group, and there's no longer any group capturing the username alone, which is probably not what OP wants