# How to make a regex to match string that starts with 0-9 or a-z with accents and must accept only this special character - _ ' between words?

Tags: java, regex

My pattern must match a String that:

- Can start with number
- Can start with letters with accents or without accents too
- Can't start with spaces
- Can't start with special characters
- Allow spaces between words
- Do not accept special character except: - _ '

My current patter is: `^[^_\W][\p{L}\s0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ.'-]+$`

Valid examples:

> Blockquote
>
> João Antonio
>
> João-Antonio
>
> João's Company
>
> Peter Müller
>
> François Hollande
>
> Patrick O'Brian
>
> Silvana Koch-Mehrin

Invalid examples:

> Company N@me
>
> 100% Company
>
> \Company
>
> \s Company
>
> _Blockquote

Please help me!

Comment: Will `^[_\pL]+(?:[-'_\p{Z}]+\pL+)*$` work for you?

Comment: no :(

this not work for me, my string must not start with special characters, spaces and whatever character different of numbers and letters.

Comment: `[_\pL]+` doesn't include any space or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

First letter:

- Start with number, letter
- Exclude accents and special chars

`[^\W_]`

Rest of the text:

- Include number, letter and accents
- Include `_`, `-`, `'` and

`[0-9]` & `[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]` & `[_\-\' ]`

Here you are:

```
^[^\W_][0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\' ]+$
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics)

When you have to deal with complicated Regex, use the [Regexr'](https://regexr.com/)!

Comment: This not work for me, my string must not start with special characters, spaces and whatever character different of numbers and letters.

Comment: Hey, did you modify your valid examples? haha, _Blockquote was part of it! Whatever, I corrected my code for you. <3

But man, you MUST know how to use RegEx. This is basic knowledge you must have as a scientist. I know, it's not fun, bt you have to! PLEASE, USE https://regex101.com/ or https://regexr.com/. You will learn quickly and become a pro at it!

Comment: Yes i modified and guy I asked  because I needed help.

Answer (score 0):

My best was:

```
/^[^_\W][\p{L}\s0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ.'-]+$/gi
```

Test: https://regexr.com/521r2

Answer (score 0):

I think the requirements are not too clear but based on your examples:

```
^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ][ '_-a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+$


^                        = beginning of line
$                        = end of line
[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]        = matches all these characters specified including one with accents
[ '_-a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]    = same as above except it includes the quote, blank space, underscore
+                        = one or more (greedy)
```

See this for more details and examples [link](https://regex101.com/r/qJo95s/1)

Best.