# Regex not finding two letter words that include Swedish letters

Tags: javascript, regex, symbols

So I am very new with Regex and I have managed to create a way to check if a specific word exists inside of a string without just being part of another word.

Example:
I am looking for the word "banana".
banana == true, bananarama == false

This is all fine, however a problem occurs when I am looking for words containing Swedish letters (Å,Ä,Ö) with words containing only two letters.

Example:
I am looking for the word "på" in a string looking like this:   "på påsk"
and it comes back as negative.
However if I look for the word "påsk" then it comes back positive.
This is the regex I am using:

```js
const doesWordExist = (s, word) => new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'i').test(s);
stringOfWords = "Färg på plagg";
console.log(doesWordExist(stringOfWords, "på"))
//Expected result: true
//Actual result: false
```

However if I were to change the word "på" to a three letter word then it comes back true:

```js
const doesWordExist = (s, word) => new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'i').test(s);
stringOfWords = "Färg pås plagg";
console.log(doesWordExist(stringOfWords, "pås"))
//Expected result: true
//Actual result: true
```

I have been looking around for answers and I have found a few that have similar issues with Swedish letters, none of them really look for only the word in its entirity.
Could anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you need RegEx for your use case? If you are looking for a whole word in a sentence, RegEx is probably overkill. RegEx excels in cases where you need to match on more complex patterns.

Comment: Well, after I have checked if the words exists i use regex to find out where the word is located so that I can edit the word however I wish. And I don't know if there is an easy way to do that without regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` strictly depends on the characters matched by `\w`, which is a [short-hand character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

For obtaining a similar behaviour you must re-implement its functionality, for example like this:

```js
const swedishCharClass = '[a-zäöå]';
const doesWordExist = (s, word) => new RegExp(
    '(?<!' + swedishCharClass + ')' + word + '(?!' + swedishCharClass + ')', 'i'
).test(s);

console.log(doesWordExist("Färg på plagg",  "på"));  // true
console.log(doesWordExist("Färg pås plagg", "pås")); // true
console.log(doesWordExist("Färg pås plagg", "på"));  // false
```

For more complex alphabets, I'd suggest you to take a look at [Concrete Javascript Regex for Accented Characters (Diacritics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499).

Comment: Thank you so much!! :D
I just finished school for front-end development, but I haven't been using Regex that much so far. :)