# How can I make this regex ignores special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that transform a uppercase/lowercase string in a capitalized string. The problem in that in my country it's normal to have special characteres in the name, and it bugs my response

```js
const updatedInput = input
            .replace(/\w+/g, (txt) => {
              return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            })
            .trim();
```

If I use this method with "JOAO CARLOS NOBREGA ", the return is "Joao Carlos Nobrega". But if I use this method with "JOÃO CARLOS NOBREGA ", the return is "JoãO Carlos Nobrega". How can I solve this?

Comment: Use `.replace(/\S+/g,`...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to match *word* characters. As you found out the pre-defined character group `\w` is useless as soon as diacritic marks are involved like in `João` or `Günther` or `øl` or `René`.
Your options are:

- to match anything that is **not** whitespace, or
- to [match anything in a carefully crafted character range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26900132/1280867), or
- to split the string up on whitespace and hyphens

I would probably do something like this:

```
const letter = '[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]';
const nonLetter = '[^A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]';
const initialLetter = `(?<=${nonLetter}|^)${letter}`;
const capitalize = (string) => string.replace(
  new RegExp(initialLetter, 'g'),
  (match) => match.toUpperCase(),
);
const updatedInput = capitalize(input.trim().toLowerCase());
```

I tested with `JANA GÜNTHER-ÄLZBÄCHER` and got `Jana Günther-Älzbächer` and I tested with `JOÃO CARLOS NOBREGA` and got `João Carlos Nobrega`.