# Extract mulitline regexp and parse newlines when needed

Tags: regex, ansible, findall, ansible-filter

I am trying to extract 2 lines (multiple times) from a specific multilines log including accented caracters (I cannot change the log).
(*the raw log file is available for consultation, but I want to show a summary of the pb from ansible playbook logs*).

The logs I am trying to parse look like :

*_

02/11/2021 17:14:20;...

02/11/2021 17:14:20;==================================

02/11/2021 17:14:20;Starting test for : OUTBOUND RabbitMQ

02/11/2021 17:14:51;**Error validating properties for broker : OUTBOUND RabbitMQ

java.lang.Exception: ERREUR::Exception lors de l'ouverture du channel[Connection timed out: connect]**

at com.mom.utils.ClientUtils.openChannel(ClientUtils.java:80) ~[classes/:na]

at com.mom.properties.RabbitMqOutboundProperties.testConfig(RabbitMqOutboundProperties.java:61) ~[classes/:na]

at com.mom.BrokerConfigurationTester.main(BrokerConfigurationTester.java:73) ~[classes/:na]

02/11/2021 17:14:51;==========================================

02/11/2021 17:14:51;...

_*

For that, I have an ansible task that looks like that :

```
 - name: showing Errors and Exception
   debug:
     msg: "{{ item }}"
   with_items:
    - "{{ test_result.stdout_lines| string | regex_findall ('(Error validating properties for broker :)[a-zA-Z0-9 '']*$.^((?!Exception).)*Exception:[^\n]*',multiline=True) }}"
# one test among many
```

Unfortunately, what works from [regexp tester](https://regex101.com/r/WO9spG/1) or [here](https://regex101.com/r/od4POY/1), does not from Ansible *regexp_findall* filter.

My main pb is that I (think I) need "**multiline=true**" in order to catch the 2 lines in a row, but then I cannot stop the catch at the end of the line (because basically ".*$" will not stop at then end of the line but at the end of the text).
And as far as I know, "all but new line" ([^\n]*) is not going to work from ansible regexp (or not the way I tried)

I have tried all the solutons from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics), but they do not work from ansible filter.
Accented caracters cause encoding error (not "UTF8"), and caracters class \u00C0 are treated like range ("from \u to 0")
So basically, I am trying to find how I can perform this with ansible (and maybe underlying python?)

Any tip?

Comment: Don't know the regex engine but the simplest way to get two adjacent lines with specific text in each line is something like [(Error validating properties for broker :).*(?:\r?\n|\r)(.*?)Exception:.*](https://regex101.com/r/3KGPfI/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suggest you to use stdout instead stdout_lines:

```
- name: test regex
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: trap the log in register
      command: cat logs/testfile.log 
      register: output

    - name: Print output
      debug: 
        var: output 

    - name: build log
      set_fact: 
        log: "{{ output.stdout | regex_findall('([0-9 :/;]+Error validating properties for broker :.+)\n(.+)') }}"

    - name: Print log
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ item }}" 
      loop: "{{ log }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=['02/11/2021 17:14:51;Error validating properties for broker : OUTBOUND RabbitMQ', "java.lang.Exception: ERREUR::Exception lors de l'ouverture du channel[Connection timed out: connect]"]) => 
  msg:
  - '02/11/2021 17:14:51;Error validating properties for broker : OUTBOUND RabbitMQ'
  - 'java.lang.Exception: ERREUR::Exception lors de l''ouverture du channel[Connection timed out: connect]'
ok: [localhost] => (item=['02/11/2021 17:14:53;Error validating properties for broker : INBOUND MqSeries', "com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Echec de la connexion au gestionnaire de files d'attente 'QMFINOUT' à l'aide du mode de connexion 'Client' et du nom d'hôte 'Client'."]) => 
  msg:
  - '02/11/2021 17:14:53;Error validating properties for broker : INBOUND MqSeries'
  - 'com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Echec de la connexion au gestionnaire de files d''attente ''QMFINOUT'' à l''aide du mode de connexion ''Client'' et du nom d''hôte ''Client''.'
```

Comment: it works like a charm. Thanks for the solution, and the tip : stdout instead of stdout_lines works fine!

Comment: yes stdout is a string, stdout_lines is a list of lines