# Remove lowercase letters from city names to generate acronyms if the names contain multiple words on Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, replace, google-sheets-formula, re2

City names that contain multiple words I want to become acronyms from your capital letters:

```
Rio de Janeiro
São Paulo
Osnabruck
Brøndby County
```

Expected Output:

```
R.J.
S.P.
Osnabruck
B.C.
```

I understand that to do this I first have to `SPLIT` the words with `" "`, remove the lowercase letters and then `JOIN` with `"."`:

```
=IF(FIND(" ",A1),JOIN(".",SPLIT(A1," ")),A1)
```

But I don't know how I can remove the lowercase letters to leave only uppercase letters.

Note: I thought of using `SUBSTITUTE(...,{all lowercase alphabet list},"")` or use REGEX like a `[^a-z]`, but there is a problem, if there are letters from other languages that are not used in my language, there will always appear a lowercase letter or other.

For example:

```
ø
```

Is there a way to separate without specifying letter by letter in a list to substitute or basic regex thath contains only basic language for english and portuguese?

Comment: I would look into regular expressions to achieve that. Search with google on ‘google sheets regex’. You will find examples.

Comment: Hi @Gabe the regex templates that my knowledge can understand, it is necessary to specify the sequence base in capital letters such as ```[^a-z]``` so that it can analyze, in this case, the use would be limited such as the list via ```SUBSTITUTE``` that I commented in relation to lowercase letters in other languages such as a letter ```ø```

Comment: Maybe the excepted answer to this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regular-expression-for-accented-characters-diacritics/26900132#26900132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4, "\s"), 
 SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A4, "[^A-Z ]", )), " ", ".")&".", A1:A4))
```

[image]