# Normalize Regex to Match special UTF-8 Characters

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

I want to check I evaluate some special UTF-8 Characters, like T̈, in my Input Field.
I tried to use this Regex:

```
\u0054(\u0300|\u0304|\u0308|\u0315|\u031B)
```

Sadly, it doesn't work.
My Character List only contains the Codepoints (0054 0308).

How can I archive the regex checks for the upper symbol?

Comment: Is this of any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regular-expression-for-accented-characters-diacritics