# `Backward slash + b` does not work as expected on regex

Tags: javascript, regex

With JS, it's a known problem that `\b` does not work well with strings containing special chars (JS engine believes chars like `ç` are word bondaries).

So I have this code:

```
"aaa aabb cc ccc abba".replace(/\b((.)\2+)\b|(.)\3+/g,"$1$3");
```

It correctly returns `aaa ab cc ccc aba`. However, if the input string has special chars, it does not work anymore, for example:

```
"ááá áább çç ççç ábbá".replace(/\b((.)\2+)\b|(.)\3+/g,"$1$3");
```

The code above returns `á ább ç ç ábbá` which is not expecetd, it should have been `ááá áb çç ççç ábá`.

So I decided I didnt want to use `\b` anymore because I will only accept word boundaries as   (space) and begginig/end of string (^ or $). So I tried this regex:

```
"ááá áább çç ççç ábbá".replace(new RegExp("(^| )((.)\\3+)( |$)|(.)\\5+","g"),"$1$2$4$5");
```

It returned `ááá áb çç ç ábá` which is almost correct, it should have returned `ááá áb çç ççç ábá`.

How can I make the last regex work without using lookheads, lookbehind, lookaround... Is there an easy fix to the last regex? Or, is there a fix to the `\b` that makes `\b` work as expected?

Comment: I don't see an actual problem statement here, and I suggest you add one.

Comment: You could [match those characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regular-expression-for-accented-characters-diacritics) like https://regex101.com/r/ZQLdYE/1

Comment: *JS engine believes chars like ç are word bondaries* - do you believe otherwise? Are you correct?

Comment: Or `const regex = /((?: |^)([\p{L}\p{M}])\2+(?= |$))|([\p{L}\p{M}])(?=\3)/gu;` See https://regex101.com/r/LH61YB/1

Comment: (Have you got your regex engine in Unicode aware mode?)