# regular expressions and unicode

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, match

I'm trying to validate this regular expression with JavaScript. What I need it to do is check if at least 2 words are entered. By words I mean strings with any characters except some specific. Everything is good until I end a string with a special unicode character, such as "ā". Then the expression fails to validate. Currently the expression looks like this -
`/^([^<>\\\/\?&{};#{}\+\*()"=%@,:0-9]{1,}\w){2,}$/i`

Any ideas on how to validate unicode expressions in this case?

Comment: [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/)?

Comment: See [Regular expression to match non-english characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters), particularly the comments to the accepted answer. And BTW, you have two `{}` in your character class. And what are you considering to be a valid word separator?

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7578937/626273)

Comment: `/^([^<>\\\/\?&{};#\+\*()"=%@,:0-9\s]+(\s+|$)){2,}$/i`  <- try that?  You're matching white space with your character class, I think you want to avoid that.  Also:  I think you're using `\w` as a whitespace matcher, but that is not what it does.  `\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so I switched it to `(\s+|$)` (whitespace or end of string).

Comment: Thanks, the expression posted above seems to be working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

On most programming lang, you would try this Unicode Regex:

```
/^([^<>\\\/\?&{};#{}\+\*()"=%@,:0-9\s]{1,}\p{L}){2,}$/ims
```

Or like this

```
/^([^\P]{1,}\p{L}){2,}$/ims
```

However, JS doesnt support Unicode that easily :(

See here for example: [Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode)