# Javascript Regex can't match ellipsis

Tags: javascript, regex, match, ellipsis

The current REGEX I'm using is the following one:

```
var sentences = fulltext.match(/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g);
```

That returns an array with the sentences split INCLUDING the spaces (I need all the characters). Problem is, it does not work with ellipsis "..." and I guess neither it does with other unconventional forms of punctuation.

How can I fix my REGEX to match this and other forms of punctuation?

Is there any *noob* friendly example driven guide to REGEX out there?

Comment: Ellipsis also have their own character / code point -- [U+2026](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis#Computer_representations) or `\u2026` -- that are distinct from 3 consecutive `.`s (U+002E).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript regular expression for punctuation (international)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576945/javascript-regular-expression-for-punctuation-international)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unicode of ellipsis is `\u2026`.

So you can use `\u2026` to match an ellipsis .

**Code** :

```
var fulltext= "First sentence… Second sentence. ";
fulltext.match(/([^.?!;\u2026]+[.?!;\u2026]+)/g);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
["First sentence…", " Second sentence."]
```

**[DEMO and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/dC8iX3/3)**

Comment: Thanks for the Demo + Explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can just add the ellipsis (and any other punctuation characters) to your character sets.

```
var input = "First sentence… Second sentence. ";
input.match(/[^\.\?!;…]+[\.\?!;…]+/g);
```

Result:

```
["First sentence…", " Second sentence."]
```